# Not Specifying an Axis

Tags: mdx

I am trying to write an MDX Code which has all the members of my cube in the row. However when I specify the row, it mentions that I must ALSO specify Columns. But if I do not set an ON ROW nor an ON Column, my code does not validate.

How do I put all my members in a row, and have a single data column be returned?

Comment: Are you trying to display the caption of each member?

Comment: Please provide the code.

Answer (score 0):

In `mdx` ON COLUMNS is axis 0 and ON ROWS is axis 1. For an mdx statement to be valid it must have at least an axis 0 .... this is one of the rules of the language, no getting around it.

Quite often if I need lots of information in my `ON ROWS` but the columns needs to be a single column then I will select a dimension I am not using e.g. Language, and then use that selected dimensions ALL member for COLUMNS - just to obey the rule. e.g.

```
SELECT 
[Language].[Language].[All] ON 0, //<<JUST A DUMMY ENTRY BUT MUST BE AN ALL MEMBER OF A DIMENSION
...
...
```

Comment: OK so sounds like I can't do what I want to do, which is put all dimension in a row.